# prevent PyQt's QActions from automatic triggers

Tags: python, qt, qt4, pyqt, pyqt4

**UPDATE** edited to add examples and to trim some content. (re-open, please?)

Python's Qt implementation, PyQt, has been serving me well, but aspects of it still very much confuse me.

Right now I have a problem with events being triggered by default from things that I don't want them to and an inability to differentiate between something that I want to trigger it and something I don't want to.

I am building a context menu that pops up new actions within it when you click on an existing action. Here's pseudocode as an example:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui,QtCore

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.menubar = QtGui.QMenuBar(self)
        self.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.menu = MyMenu(self)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menu.menuAction())
        self.menu.setTitle('Menu')
        self.listy = []
        self.installEventFilter(self.eventFilter)

class MyMenu(QtGui.QMenu):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        QtGui.QMenu.__init__(self)
        self.quit_action = QtGui.QAction("Close",self)
        self.add_action = QtGui.QAction("Add action",self)
        self.new_action = QtGui.QAction(" New action",self)
        self.new_action.setVisible(False)
        self.add_action.triggered.connect(self.toggleActionOn)
        for i in self.quit_action,self.add_action,self.new_action:
            self.addAction(i)
        self.installEventFilter(self)
    def toggleActionOn(self):
        self.new_action.setVisible(True)
```

It works great except for the fact that I've made a race condition: any time I click on an action, the menu automatically closes. Since these built-in triggers are getting in the way of my own triggers, I want to stop them from happening.

I tried intercepting the close and mouse-release events:

```
class MyMenu(QtGui.QMenu):
    def closeEvent(self,event):
        ...
        event.accept()
    ...
    def mouseReleaseEvent(self,event):
        ...
        event.accept()
    ...
```

...which seemed useless because the event received had no info about the sender. It did however tell me the sequence of events that my clicking caused in the QMenu: `MouseButtonPress`, `Close`, `Hide`, `HideToParent`, `Enter`, `Leave`.

I added an `eventFilter`:

```
class MyMenu(QtGui.QMenu):
    ...
    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        print 'EVENT RECEIVED'
        print obj, event
        if ( obj is self or obj is self.new_action ) and event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.Close:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

The 'event' given does not have any element telling me what's the sender of the 'close'.

In desperation, I tried to disconnect the action, `new_action.disconnect(QtCore.QEvent.Close)`, and other similarly non-sensical ploys.

Does anyone know how to "disconnect" an object from it's related "close" event OR how to more selectively prohibit the close event from occurring??

**UPDATE** As Pavel Strakhov pointed out, the problem is with my misunderstanding the handling of events. To stop `QMenu.Close` from passing, I had to filter for the original event, `MouseReleaseEvent` or `MousePressEvent`, that started the chain of events and it happens to be attributable to the location of the `QAction` that I needed to identify.

Comment: Please prune the wall of text, and post some actual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closing menu cannot be prevented using intercepting close event. Closing and hiding is handled internally in `QMenu`. Once an action was triggered, there is nothing that could stop `QMenu` from hiding.

We should make `QMenu` believe that the action has not been triggered at all. I managed to do this by filtering MouseButtonRelease event:

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.menu = None


    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        menu = QMenu()
        self.menu = menu
        menu.installEventFilter(self)
        self.quit_action = menu.addAction("Close")
        self.add_action = menu.addAction("Add action")
        menu.exec_(self.mapToGlobal(event.pos()))

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        print(obj, self.menu)
        if obj == self.menu:
            if event.type() == QEvent.MouseButtonRelease:
                action = self.menu.actionAt(event.pos())
                if action:
                    if action == self.quit_action:
                        return False
                    elif action == self.add_action:
                        self.menu.addAction("New action")
                        self.menu.exec_()
                        return True
        return False
```

When user clicks "New action", new item is added to the menu immediately without hiding and showing it. However use this code carefully. This should be considered as hack. There is no guarantee that filtering `MouseButtonRelease` will be enough on all systems. Using recursive `QMenu::exec` calls is also questionable.

When returning True from eventFilter, the event will be blocked and QAction will not be triggered, so the connected slot will not be executed. You need to call appropriate code manually in eventFilter (as shown for "add_action" case in the code above).

Now about your attempts. `QObject::disconnect` function operates signals and slots. You cannot just magically disconnect "QtCore.QEvent.Close" from anything because it's not a signal or slot. It's just a enum value. Events are not signals. Using event filters or subclassing QMenu was a right idea.

Comment: Very nice. You have pointed out what I missed in my narrow vision: `close()` is attached to the object being closed and nothing more; `MouseButtonRelease` and other "mouse" events are tied to a position relatable to the object being clicked. I modified a few things, not sure if they matter: had a permanent menu attached to the `MainWindow` object instead of creating a new one on each click and also using `menu.popup()` instead of `menu.exec_()`.
I knew most of the things I tried to `disconnect` didn't make sense, but I was desparate.